# Android mp4 video from online getting corrupted when downloaded

Tags: android, video, download, mp4, dropbox

I am working on an application that plays a video file on a loop. Up until now I was just mounting the device and copying the video file onto the SD card and then using the file path to start it up on my VideoView. I am trying to implement a way that I can remotely update what video it plays so I have moved to storing my video online. Inside the app I check for a local copy and download if it doesn't exist, or if there is a newer one. I have tested it on two different video files both .mp4s. After downloading one of them plays the first time but upon trying to start again for the loop it tells me video cannot be played. The other won't even play the first time, it just gives me the dialog that says the video cannot be played. Both of these files work correctly with my app if I copy them onto the SD card via the USB cable. They work if I exit my app and manually download them with something else(dropbox) but not if I download them from within my app. Here is the code I am using to download the file:

```
public static void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/myfile.mp4"); 
        File file = new File(PATH + fileName);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(myTag, "download begining");
        Log.d(myTag, "download url:" + url);
        Log.d(myTag, "downloaded file name:" + fileName);


        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        Log.i(myTag, "Opened Connection");

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Log.i(myTag, "Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos =  new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        Log.i(myTag, "Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream");
        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */

        int current = 0;
        Log.i(myTag, "About to write");
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(current);
        }



        fos.close();
        Log.d(myTag, "download ready in"
                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
                + " sec");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(myTag, "Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

I know the dropbox url in this snippet is not correct I changed it only for this post, in my app the url is pointing to a file correctly. And the variable PATH thats used when creating the File is set in my code outside of this snippet.

Is there something about this code snippet that could be corrupting my mp4 files?

Comment: Try downloading the video using your method to the sdcard and then pull the file off the sdcard using the usb cable. See if that file plays.

Comment: I don't have a player that will play .mp4 on my computer. I suspect that it won't though I looked at the file properties and the ones that my method is downloading are a few bytes smaller than they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method was corrupting the file somehow, I am still not quite sure how but I changed part of it and now it is fixed.

I am now using this:

```
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            fos.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

instead of the old while loop and it works correctly.

Comment: I almost suggested this but didn't have time to test. The stream is backed by the file, so if you return from the method without flushing the stream, some bytes can remain in the object stream without making it to the backing store. Your call to `flush()` ensures that the bytes are removed from the memory object and placed in the file.

Comment: I confused myself into thinking that the .flush() call wasn't the problem for a while. I accidentally called flush() on the FileOutputStream rather than the BufferedOutputStream which was actually doing the writing. So it didn't fix anything. In figuring this out I realized that the BufferedOutputStream wasn't necessary.

Comment: Buffered input and output streams with show a performance improvement over non-buffered streams. You should put them back in if it isn't onerous for your application.